# How to best search and update two arrays of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I have a Person object here with the following two attributes: firstname and mood. Assume the firstname attribute is unique.

If I have an array () of 3 Person objects (assume each line is a single person object):

```
Alison, Happy
Bob, Sad
Charles, Happy
```

If a have a second array for example of 3 people (from JSON array):

```
Alison, Sad
Bob, Happy
Jordan, Sad
```

I want the most efficient way to be able to iterate through the second array to update items in the first array. The way I think of it is with 2 for loops. So for example:

1st iteration, sees Alison, searches through first array for Alison, updates Alison to Sad. 2nd iteration, sees Bob, searches through...etc
3rd iteration, sees Jordan, searches through 1st array for Jordon, does not find... pushes new object onto array with Jordan, Sad.

Now I know that the array may not be the best way to do this, if there is a better way to accomplish this without the 1st array being an array.. could be a map, etc. What I care about is performance as the method i described is incredibly inefficient for many people for example if the arrays were of size 100.

Please help, would appreciate greatly.

Answer (score 0):

This depends somewhat on your browser and library environment. There is `Array.indexOf('value')`, but that won't work in IE, and it's probably just doing a (optimized) loop behind the scenes anyway.

If you have a lot of data, and it's likely to be sorted, which doesn't seem to be the case for you, it's better to do a binary search. In other words, take the value from the middle of the data set and compare it to your query. If it's greater, your next query is the middle value of the first half of the set of values, and so on, until you get it.

Not necessarily a solution to the performance problem (though better than some) but a good alternative for this kind of work in terms of reduction of coding overhead is the [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) library. With underscore you could use `_detect` to fetch your value and then just use `Array.push` if not found.

Answer (score 0):

If each person has a unique id or reference, you can put them in an object and use the id as a key, then do:

```
if (sadBob.id in personCollection) {
    // sadBob is already there
    personCollection.update(sadBob);

} else {
    // add sadBob
    personCollection.addPerson(sadBob);
}
```

Alternatively, you might add a property to the person objects in array2 that is their index in array1 when you create them. So if they don't have an index, they aren't in array1. If they have an index, you can go straight there (which is essentially the same as the above with an object and using the array index as the reference or id).

Comment: What type is person collection?

Comment: @Utiveras - an object. It might help to know a bit more about how you create *person* objects and and how they end up in the person array.

Comment: function Person(name, mood) {this.name=name, this.mood=mood} <- That is how the objects are created.